# C# INSERT into an Access DB Memo type field is truncated when using OLEDB 12.0

Tags: c#, ms-access

This has been frustrating me and I have yet to find a working answer or solution. There have been a lot of posts and replies, but none that actually explain a working solution.

The Access vulnerableconfiguration  table consists of:

```
Field Name        Data Type
cveid             Test
logicaltest       Memo
```

The relevant code bits where a completely empty vulnerableconfiguration table is populated with completely unique data:

```
mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + accessDb + ";Persist Security Info=False");
mycon.Open();

...

insertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO vulnerableconfiguration (cveid, logicaltest) VALUES (@cveid, @logicaltest);", mycon);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@cveid", OleDbType.Char).Value = cve_id);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@logicaltest", OleDbType.LongWChar).Value = vulnerable_configuration);
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The logicaltest field values are truncated and I have no clue why. Even the 1st record is truncated from 780 characters to 370! All the memo fields should fit into the memo size limitation. There's no error. I've debugged it and the value set in the insertCommand Parameters has the full value, but when the command is executed, the Access DB has a truncated value.

If anyone has any ideas, it would be great for everyone who's had this issue.

Please don't refer me to http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html, none of those cases deal with this straight forward Access insert case. Also, Access 2007/2010 does not have a max length setting for a Memo data type, and it's supposed to grow.

Why am I using Access? This is for an import tool for an Access DB, which is used for look up purposes. Someone else can write some simple queries and reports to get the info they want from it. Not being used as a back-end, and MSSQL is too heavy for this purpose.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Switched to OleDbType.LongWChar for the memo field parameter but I'm still getting the same truncation once the Access record is populated.

Comment: have you double checked to see if the Memo Field is however declared as Memo.. also is this for a 32bit or 64 bit  OS, make sure that you are using the correct Provider for example you are using Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 .. is this for windows 7, XP, Vista...??? Also is there a way to Cast the Memo Field to a different datatype like Text, or Binary, etc..?

Comment: also wrap a Try Catch around this ----> insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I have try and catches, but ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't thrown an exception. The OLEDB gobbles up the query and continues.

Comment: Good question! This is a 64-bit Windows 7 system using Visual Studio 2010, and the app is a C# application with platform x86 set. I've also tried targeting x64 and "Any CPU", but the results are the same, and the 1st record truncation is also in the same place.

Comment: Have you changed the OldeDBType to the following line 
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@logicaltest", OleDbType.LongVarWChar).Value = vulnerable_configuration);

Comment: @DJKRAZE's suggestion works for me (Access 2010, 64 bit Windows 7, C#)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong OleDbType per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320435

> insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@logicaltest", OleDbType.Char).Value = vulnerable_configuration);

should be

> insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@logicaltest", OleDbType.LongVarWChar).Value = vulnerable_configuration);

Comment: You are correct, but the problem still persists. After switching to LongVarWChar the data is still truncated to the same length.

Comment: How are you inspecting the value being inserted to detect the truncation?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the OleDbType.Char for the Memo field incorrectly it looks like.. you need a larger field to hold the Memo data, try OleDbType.LongVarWChar

looking at this link as well it will be very helpful 
[OleDbType DataTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx)

Comment: Good catch. No that didn't do the trick though. I switched to both OleDbType.LongVarChar and OleDbType.LongVarWChar with no difference. I also debugged the appl and inspected the Parameters item to make sure the value was indeed the full data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the OleDbType.Char data type for the Memo field, it is normal to have the value truncated. For the Memo field, use the OleDbType.LongVarWChar for the data type. If you have more trouble with other data type, take a look at [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320435), it has all the a good list of equivalence for Acces to OleDb

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/4ee6d674-5942-494e-8d7b-9c6f377d0ab6/

I have solved the problem by change the text format of the field to be 'Rich Text'.